# Trying to convert values in SQL to Unix Timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have a Wordpress table that has a bunch of values currently in date format MM/DD/YYYY. This query successfully shows me the Unix Timestamps for them:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(`meta_value`,'%m/%d/%Y'))
FROM `wp_6222_postmeta`
WHERE `meta_key`="wpcf-start-date"
```

But I'm struggling to figure out how to write those values back into the field properly. I tried this query and it didn't work:

```
UPDATE 'wp_6222_postmeta'
SET 'meta_value' = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(`meta_value`,'%m/%d/%Y'))
WHERE 'meta_key' = 'wpcf-start-date'
```

Comment: How didn't it work? Did you get wrong values, or an error message?

Comment: I was getting a syntax error that wasn't very clear on which part but I'm assuming a problem with the UPDATE syntax of some kind.

Comment: Ok the syntax error ended up being the addition of quotation marks for the column fields which UPDATE must not like. Removing those gave me NULL values but the query ran. I then found I had to wrap the timestamp conversion in a SELECT function. Here's the code I ran that successfully converted all the fields:

    `UPDATE wp_6222_postmeta
    SET meta_value = (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(`meta_value`,'%m/%d/%Y')))
    WHERE meta_key='wpcf-end-date'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasting answer here since I couldn't answer it before because my account was too new.

Ok the syntax error ended up being the addition of quotation marks for the column fields which UPDATE must not like. Removing those gave me NULL values but the query ran. I then found I had to wrap the timestamp conversion in a SELECT function. Here's the code I ran that successfully converted all the fields:

```
UPDATE wp_6222_postmeta
SET meta_value = (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(meta_value`,'%m/%d/%Y')))
WHERE meta_key='wpcf-end-date'
```